# django channels websocket connect not working

Tags: django, channel, django-channels

I am trying to run the multichat project from django channels-examples on a server. It works locally on a windows machine but when I put this on the linux server and start it with runserver it does not:

```
./manage.py runserver
```

Then when I call up the website, it is shown correctly but as soon as the JS sends it websocket request I always get this reponse:

```
[2016/08/02 14:35:48] HTTP GET /chat/stream/ 404 [0.04, 127.0.0.1:40186]
....(many lines of this)
```

So the websocket request is handled as an http request. The response should be this:

```
[2016/08/02 16:34:45] WebSocket CONNECT /chat/stream/ [127.0.0.1:60250]
```

I have no clue where this is going wrong. The routing of http versus websocket seems to be done somewhere deep inside daphne/twisted/...

My channel settings are (if that is of any help at all):

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(redis_host, 62031)],
        },
        "ROUTING": "multichat.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

Twisted version is 16.2.0.

Any help or hint in what direction to look is very appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am facing same problem. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Some questions/suggestions that come to mind:

Is the linux server for development or production? I.e. Is there a HTTP server or just plain DJANGO running? (In the former case you don't start with "./manage runserver".)

> "Then when I call up the website, it is shown correctly ..."

Is this because the port numbers different for the the requests? 40186 vs 60250.

You're getting a 404, e.g. url Not Found. This can be either the response of the HTTP server of from DJANGO.

Comment: I am running this with runserver - but django-channels overrides the runserver command with its own (that starts daphne and the workers). The port might indeed be the issue - every failed request shows a different port - and those ports I cannot access. But I have no clue where those port numbers are coming from.

Comment: Actually the port numbers shown should be meaninless: as this request works: [2016/08/03 07:47:51] HTTP GET /static/css/style.css 200 [0.02, 127.0.0.1:53294]
The problem seems to be that it handles an ws request as http

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the complete log ?

Try running the server with daphne and run worker

```
daphne multichat.asgi:channel_layer --port 80 --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2 
python manage.py runworker -v2
```

Use something like supervisor to do this in a better way to restart these on failure.